# Erro Tomcat 8 + Project Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat

Estou com o seguinte erro ao iniciar o projeto, alguém já teve este problema?

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyProject]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyProject]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@363d5a97]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@160839a1]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:703)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:716)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
... 13 more

Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 6 more

Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 13 more

Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Sep 06, 2016 11:23:19 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyProject]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.__stop(StandardContext.java:5551)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:832)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1012)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: Seu .war esta corrompido, se esta no servidor de produção provável que por problemas de conexão, antes de enviar o projeto rode um mvn update e um install depois clean package e envia denovo.

Comment: Estou rodando local pelo eclipse. Ele não inicia.

Comment: Executou os procedimentos acima? procure limpar a pasta work do tomcat remove a o build antigo e refaça o processo, dependendo da versão do windows também ocorrem erros quando não há permissão para o usuário de leuitura e escrita na pasta dos ervidor por ficar dentro de arquivos e programas.

Comment: O que acha mais estranho é que rodo este projeto em outra maquina normal sem erros, também rodo outro projeto que segue a mesma estrutura, mas não os mesmas dependências neste mesmo tomcat. Acredito que seja algum erro de configuração que não conseguir encontrar ainda, mas intrigante e ver ele funcionando em outra maquina a única coisa que fiz foi baixar o projeto via git e tentar rodar e nada, na maquina de origem ele funciona normal.

Comment: Estou rodando em um ambiente Mac OS, mas não acredito que o problema seja o ambiente pois rodo os outros neste mesmo eclipse + tomcat. Se eu remover o projeto e add outro ou ate sem projetos o tomcat roda normal. Também roda normal este projeto em outro ambiente que tenho em outra maquina.

Comment: Estou começando a achar que podem ser JAR que o Maven tenha baixado corrompido e umas das coisas que vejo que pode estar diferente.

Comment: só da um ls -lha para ver se as permissões estão batendo por favor.

Comment: Em qual diretório? Em não tenho a outra maquina aqui onde estou. Viajei e então baixei o projeto no Not e agora ela apresenta este problema.

Comment: onde esta o tomcat

Comment: Segue resultado:

total 184
drwxrwxrwx  15 jeremias  staff   510B Feb 17  2016 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 86 root      admin   2.9K Sep  6 09:44 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jeremias  staff    57K Feb  2  2016 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jeremias  staff   1.5K Feb  2  2016 NOTICE
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jeremias  staff   6.8K Feb  2  2016 RELEASE-NOTES
-rwxrwxrwx   1 jeremias  staff    16K Feb  2  2016 RUNNING.txt
drwxrwxrwx   8 jeremias  staff   272B Feb 17  2016 backup

Comment: drwxrwxrwx  25 jeremias  staff   850B Feb 17  2016 bin
drwxrwxrwx  11 jeremias  staff   374B Feb 17  2016 conf
drwxrwxrwx  26 jeremias  staff   884B Feb 17  2016 lib
drwxrwxrwx  76 jeremias  staff   2.5K Sep  6 09:52 logs
drwxrwxrwx   3 jeremias  staff   102B Sep  6 09:54 temp
drwxrwxrwx   7 jeremias  staff   238B Feb  2  2016 webapps
drwxrwxrwx   3 jeremias  staff   102B Feb 17  2016 work
drwxrwxrwx   5 jeremias  staff   170B Sep  6 09:51 wtpwebapps

Comment: sim, discarto que seja permissão :(

Comment: se outra app sobe de boa, pode ser algo com essa que foi corrompido para o repositório, você consegue dar clean install de boa nela ?

Comment: Vou testar. Nao havia tentado ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema. Apaguei o repositório Maven e baixei novamente e funcionou corretamente. Acredito que havia alguma lib corrompida que o erro não esta sendo exibido pelo tomcat.